# Change frame in startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I'm trying to change my UIView's frame with value I get from CMMotionManager and its method 
*- startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler*

I wrote a draft like this :

```
[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:theQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        CGRect frame = _backgroundView.frame;
        double x = motion.attitude.roll;
        frame.origin.x = x*10;
        [_backgroundView setFrame:frame];
}];
```

But my view doesn't move at all. If I log my frame I can see changes at every update ... So why my view isn't moving on screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Storyboard? The problem may be due to constraints set up in Storyboard overriding the frame change.

Change the auto-layout constraints via code and then try your frame change above.

To force change, you can use - (void)setNeedsLayout method after frame changes.